# GRPC CallError : InvalidFlags while publishing Google pub sub Topic. .net 4.5.2

Tags: .net, grpc, .net-4.5, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a web app that publishes messages to a Topic for certain user activities.
I am getting the below error every time I try to publish message to the topic in a compute engine instance.

```
PublisherClient publisher = PublisherClient.CreateAsync(new TopicName(projectId, topicName)).Result;
var t = publisher.PublishAsync(serializer.Serialize(topicName.TopicId, message));
t.Wait();
```

```
|Result="Call error: InvalidFlags"|ExTyp=System.InvalidOperationException|ExMsg=Call error: InvalidFlags
|EX=System.InvalidOperationException: Call error: InvalidFlags
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.CallErrorExtensions.CheckOk(CallError callError)
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.CallSafeHandle.StartUnary(IUnaryResponseClientCallback callback, Byte[] payload, WriteFlags writeFlags, MetadataArraySafeHandle metadataArray, CallFlags callFlags)
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.UnaryCallAsync(TRequest msg)
   at Grpc.Core.Calls.AsyncUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](CallInvocationDetails`2 call, TRequest req)
   at Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.AsyncUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.<AsyncUnaryCall>b__4_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx)
   at Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.AsyncUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext`2 context, AsyncUnaryCallContinuation`2 continuation)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.AsyncUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.Publisher.PublisherClient.PublishAsync(PublishRequest request, CallOptions options)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall.GrpcCallAdapter`2.CallAsync(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`2.<<WithRetry>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

The compute engine instance is using custom service account with necessary IAM permissions.

Another thing to point out is that I recreated the environment in another GCP compute instance Jump server, within the same project, by building the application using Visual studio with the same source code for remote debugging. I am able to publish topics there. This server has the same IAM permissions.

The custom service account has the `"roles/pubsub.publisher"`role.

Target `.net framework - 4.5.2`

`using Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1;  v1.1.0`

The below link points to similar issue in Google ads client library, and as per the google representative, it is an issue in the library.
https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/zSYZKy4J41o

I know the call error is part of the enum
https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/grpc/grpc/+/chromium-deps/2016-07-19/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/Internal/CallError.cs , but I don't know why it is failing in the main GCE instance.

If this does not work I will have to go with API calls, but is there any way I can get this client library work?

I have implemented **SecretManager** and **StorageClient** , but this issue caught me off guard.

Let me know if I have to share more info. Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: I don't know what the error means here, but side observation: don't use .Result or .Wait(); for unary calls, gRPC usually emits both sync and async patterns; either await the async version, or use the sync version

Answer (score 0):

I've not used C# very much recently so apologies in advance.

Using .NET Core 5.0 (!?) and both the old version (v1.1.0) and current (v.2.6.0) versions of Cloud PubSub v1, work for me:

```cs
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace app
{
    class Program
    {

        static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
        {
            string projectId=Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROJECT");
            
            string topicId="foo";

            PublisherClient publisher = await PublisherClient.CreateAsync(
                new TopicName(projectId, topicId));
            var t = await publisher.PublishAsync(
                Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello Freddie"));

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```sh
gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull foo-sub \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(message.data)"
Hello Freddie
```

Perhaps you've a dependency conflict between the 2 VMs? I ran the above in Microsoft's .NET Core container which provides consistency.

app.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1" Version="2.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Core" Version="2.40.0-pre1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```